# DEADLINE scheduling policy not found

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, sched-deadline

I want to implement the DEADLINE scheduling policy in C. I know the feature is implemented since `Linux 3.14.10` and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 `Linux #### 3.17.0-031700-lowlatency #201410060605 SMP PREEMPT` which should be recent enough. I develop the program with Eclipse (launched as sudo).

I've defined `_GNU_SOURCE` and included `sched.h` and I'm still unable to use the keyword `SCHED_DEADLINE`, to define a `struct sched_attr` or to use function like `sched_getattr`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
```

None of these keywords nor functions are defined in my `/usr/include/` folder but I've managed to find them in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include/`. 
I've tried to include this folder in my project's build options but it seems to generate link error.

I'm not really used to C developpment (I'm originally a JS developper) so if someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this, that would be very nice.

Content of the `/usr/include/linux/sched.h`

```
#ifndef _LINUX_SCHED_H
#define _LINUX_SCHED_H

/*
 * cloning flags:
 */
#define CSIGNAL     0x000000ff  /* signal mask to be sent at exit */
#define CLONE_VM    0x00000100  /* set if VM shared between processes */
#define CLONE_FS    0x00000200  /* set if fs info shared between processes */
#define CLONE_FILES 0x00000400  /* set if open files shared between processes */
#define CLONE_SIGHAND   0x00000800  /* set if signal handlers and blocked signals shared */
#define CLONE_PTRACE    0x00002000  /* set if we want to let tracing continue on the child too */
#define CLONE_VFORK 0x00004000  /* set if the parent wants the child to wake it up on mm_release */
#define CLONE_PARENT    0x00008000  /* set if we want to have the same parent as the cloner */
#define CLONE_THREAD    0x00010000  /* Same thread group? */
#define CLONE_NEWNS 0x00020000  /* New namespace group? */
#define CLONE_SYSVSEM   0x00040000  /* share system V SEM_UNDO semantics */
#define CLONE_SETTLS    0x00080000  /* create a new TLS for the child */
#define CLONE_PARENT_SETTID 0x00100000  /* set the TID in the parent */
#define CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID    0x00200000  /* clear the TID in the child */
#define CLONE_DETACHED      0x00400000  /* Unused, ignored */
#define CLONE_UNTRACED      0x00800000  /* set if the tracing process can't force CLONE_PTRACE on this clone */
#define CLONE_CHILD_SETTID  0x01000000  /* set the TID in the child */
/* 0x02000000 was previously the unused CLONE_STOPPED (Start in stopped state)
   and is now available for re-use. */
#define CLONE_NEWUTS        0x04000000  /* New utsname group? */
#define CLONE_NEWIPC        0x08000000  /* New ipcs */
#define CLONE_NEWUSER       0x10000000  /* New user namespace */
#define CLONE_NEWPID        0x20000000  /* New pid namespace */
#define CLONE_NEWNET        0x40000000  /* New network namespace */
#define CLONE_IO        0x80000000  /* Clone io context */

/*
 * Scheduling policies
 */
#define SCHED_NORMAL        0
#define SCHED_FIFO      1
#define SCHED_RR        2
#define SCHED_BATCH     3
/* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
#define SCHED_IDLE      5
/* Can be ORed in to make sure the process is reverted back to SCHED_NORMAL on fork */
#define SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK     0x40000000


#endif /* _LINUX_SCHED_H */
```

**EDIT**

Files I want are located in the `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include/` folder. Anyway, I tried to add the folder to my project using several methods. Firstly using `-I` flag of gcc and next using the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable.

In both ways, gcc searched in priority in default locations and found the wrong `<sched.h>` file. I tried to used `-nostdinc` option to suppress default locations but this is even worse... I get a lot of errors.

Comment: When using `#include <linux/sched.h>`, I have `SCHED_DEADLINE` on my Debian (linux 4.4). What do you include exactly ?

Comment: You do not have it. I have the line `#define SCHED_DEADLINE 6
` after the `#define SCHED_IDLE 5`. Perhaps this is not the good linux version.

Comment: Using `<linux/sched.h>` doesn't change anything, nor using both.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that. But I can find this line in the `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include/linux/sched.h`. That's weird.

Comment: Have you SCHED_DEADLINE in your /usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include/uapi/linux/sched.h ?

Comment: Yes, and the `sched_attr` structure is also defined.

Comment: So, I think you are using a default older version of the linux api. If you try removing the older versions, perhaps it will work.

Comment: what distro are you using?

Comment: @fluter I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Boiethios How can I perform that ?

Comment: Try upgrade the kernel header package, your header package is older than the kernel package

Comment: And then just use `#include <linux/sched.h>`

Comment: After performing a `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` nothing changed, my headers seemed to be up to date.

Comment: Searched http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-headers&searchon=names it looks that Ubuntu 14.04 release is using kernel version 3.13.0-32. I guess that mean you will need to compile your own kernel from upstream source tarball.

Comment: @fluter It may be a dumb question but... I changed the kernel for a 3.17 low latency one. So, it's not enough ?

Comment: What about the Linux-headers?

Comment: I found them in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include`. If I manage to add them to my project, this should work (I hope).

Comment: If /usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include are installed by Linux-headers package, it should work. On my system, the kernel headers will install under /usr/include. So in your case, I guess just add -I//usr/src/linux-headers-3.17.0-031700/include to your make file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually upgraded to `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` with a `kernel 4.4.0-21-lowlatency` and the key word `SCHED_DEADLINE` is now defined by default.

The problem is `struct sched_attr` and methods `sched_getattr() / sched_setattr()` are still missing !

After some research (thanks Google) I found this [article](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-deadline.txt) emitted by the kernel developpers. At the end of the document, it is describe how to use deadline scheduling policy. They simply define by themselves the structure and use `syscall` for the get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

Answer may depend on distribution! this example is based on Debian 8.4

ALso, you will find two tools usefull in those situations - both available on debian's repositories - ack (**ack-grep**) and **locate**
ack will help you find given string in all subdirectories, and locate will help you find actual file (after `updatedb`) if it exist on your system. For example you can find all files like sched.h starting from root with `locate sched.h`

firsts of all you should #include if you do not posses this particular include, try to download it from repositories, in case you are using Debian - this file can be found in (prefferably latest) **libc6-dev** (notice that dev packages will contain includes and headers for development purposes) or **linux-headers**

Also if your compiler cant find *linux/sched.h* try to give compiler a path hint, in my case it would be : *gcc -I/usr/include* (which is in this case completly useless - this is default include dir in linux)

Notice that **/usr/include/linux/sched.h** and **/usr/include/sched.h** may differ slightly

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, despite `SCHED_DEADLINE` being mainline since three years ago, libc's include files are still missing the interface to the deadline scheduler (i.e., `sched_setattr()`, `sched_getattr()` and `sched_attr`, etc.). A behavior that somehow resembles [the time to get libc wrapping the `getttid()` syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9565177/2214693).

Therefore, at the moment, the best option is to [download rt-app from GitHub](https://github.com/scheduler-tools/rt-app) and use the **libdl** interface.