# Which system call macro to use

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

There are some Linux system calls (e.g., `gettid`) which have no glibc wrapper and thus must be invoked via the `syscall` function.

Looking in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h`, I see definitions like

```c
#ifdef __NR_gettid
# define SYS_gettid __NR_gettid
#endif
```

What is the reason for two aliases for the same system call number?  Is one more portable/stable?  I guess my question boils down to: Which macro should I be using in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565177/call-gettid-witin-glibc

Comment: AFAICT, the `SYS_*` macros are the traditional ones, whereas the `__NR_*` ones are a Linux kernel convention. I'd lean toward the `SYS` ones, myself.